# Limitations of Timer over ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, concurrency

What are the differences between, or respective limitations of, java's `Timer facility` and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor service`?

I know that `Timer` runs in `single` thread, but are there any other limitations apart from that?

Comment: The real question is; why use Timer at all when you can use ScheduledExecutorService?

Comment: Well I am already using Timer tasks liberally, but want to shift to Scheduled Executor. Would really like to browse through all the use-cases considering limitations and benefits.

Comment: Isn't the question is why to use Timer less ?

Comment: What is the advantage of using Timer at all?

Comment: @PeterLawrey e.g. because `ScheduledExecutorService` doesn't provide a replacement for the `Timer#schedule(TimerTask, long, long)` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71794510/3882565.

Answer (score 1):

Being single threaded is the main limitation of Timer:

- an overrun task can disrupt schedule of other tasks
- timer is not fair with tasks, for example:

  ```
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("Task#1: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
  }, 1000, 1);
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("Task#2: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
  }, 1200, 1);
  ```

would demonstrate that task#2 doesn't even get a shot at CPU time.

`ScheduledExecutorService` gives you the right level of control over level of concurrency of your tasks.

Comment: Task#2 does get a shot at CPU time. Below is the output at my CPU.        Task#1: 1400576849729
Task#1: 1400576849730
Task#1: 1400576849731
Task#1: 1400576849732
Task#1: 1400576849733
Task#1: 1400576849734
Task#1: 1400576849735
Task#2: 1400576849735
Task#2: 1400576849736
Task#1: 1400576849736
Task#1: 1400576849737
Task#2: 1400576849737