# Timer vs. ScheduledExecutorService scheduling

Tags: java, timer, scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

One of the recommended uses of the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is as a direct replacement for the [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, as discussed in numerous `StackOverflow` topics already:

- [Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)
- [Difference between TimerTask and Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)
- [What is the difference between schedule and scheduleAtFixedRate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486997/what-is-the-difference-between-schedule-and-scheduleatfixedrate)
- [Android Timer schedule vs scheduleAtFixedRate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684604/android-timer-schedule-vs-scheduleatfixedrate)

However, the naming conventions of the methods supported by `ScheduledExecutorService` and `Timer`, are not identical. For example, whereas they both have a `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method, the Timer method

- schedule​(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

does not have a namesake counterpart.

Is the `ScheduledExecutorService` method

- scheduleWithFixedDelay​(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit)

the one to use instead?

Comment: Timer is an implement Class.  ScheduledExecutorService is an interface without implementation. So we should compare Timer vs ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is an implementation class of ScheduledExecutorService interface

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
> after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given delay
> between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the
> next.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
> beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place
> at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.

I would say - Yes ;-)

Comment: Yes, so it seems, but it is not directly mentioned in any comparative discussion I have found, hence the question. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`Timer#schedule(TimerTask, long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,long,long)) has no counterpart in [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or its implementation [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). Although this method is documented as

> repeated fixed-delay execution,

it bahaves fundamentally different than [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and let alone [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). I have explained the difference between all these methods more detailed as part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71761712/3882565).