# Periodically check the database

Tags: java, service, timer, executorservice, schedule

I want to make a background service in java and I have a function to periodically check the database. If there's no email to be sent it will sleep for a few minutes and if there's an email to be sent it will run the function and send the email to the user.

My question is, which approach should I use: `Schedule` or `ExecutorService`  and what are the advantages if I use them.

Note Update*

- I'm developing in JavaEE and use the JSF framework

Comment: We need more "context"... Is your application a Java EE or a Java SE edition application? This would change a lot.

Comment: @Lorelorelore I'm developing JavaEE and use JSF framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timer vs. ScheduledExecutorService scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956511/timer-vs-scheduledexecutorservice-scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java EE then the `@Schedule` annotation should easily fit your needs. It is just simpler than managing the `ExecutorService`, and it does not requires any configuration in the application container.

```
@Schedules ({
   @Schedule(dayOfMonth="Last"),
   @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Fri", hour="23")
})
public void doPeriodicCheck() { ... }
```

As you can see, you can also combine more than one `@Schedule`, so to me it is also more flexible than `ExecutorService`.